# Linear transformation over complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to verify that I'm on the right track for this:

If $T$ is the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ (where $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and $T(x) = (a + bi) \cdot x$, find the matrix that represents $T$ for the basis $\{1, i\}$.

So $T(1) = (a + bi) \cdot 1 = a + bi$ and $T(i) = ai + bi^2 = ai - b$, and therefore the matrix that represents $T$ is $\left( \begin{array}{c} a + bi \\ ai - b \end{array} \right)$?

Or is it a linear matrix?  Or is it totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should express the result in the basis $\{1,i\}$ as well, that is
your matrix should be $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Right, makes sense, thanks!